# How do I use ruby time class to always get the EST

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, getjson

I have a rails application and i need to get the Eastern standard Time using the [Time class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm)

I am just trying to make sure that we always use eastern stand time so I can sync with a countdown every 3 seconds...

here is the code

Jquery code

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
  refresh();
  function refresh() {
    $j.getJSON("/timer", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
  }
});
```

RAILS Controller action

```
def refresh_timer
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => Time.now}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Time.now.in_time_zone 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

Or just use this if your server is configured to use EST:

`Time.now.localtime`